# Understanding Weak References

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, weak-references

Consider I have a class structure similar to this

```
class Outer extends Activity {

    Map<String, String> outerMap;

    public Map getSampleMap() {
        return sampleMap;
    }

    static class Inner {
        Map<String, String> innerMap;

        Inner(Outer outer) {
            /* Weak ref to outer class object */
            WeakReference weakref = new WeakReference<Outer>(outer);
            /* reference to the outer map using the weak ref */
            innerMap = weakref.get().getSampleMap();
        }

        void doSomething() {
            // Operations on the innerMap
        }

    }
}
```

Now in the above code structure

1. Is innerMap hold a strong reference to the outerMap ?
2. If I were to pass the innerMap in a callback such that it outlives the Outer
   Class (perhaps config changes)  would it leak ?
3. Will the outer class
   object be GC'ed ?

Can someone point me to a good source for reference.

Comment: `Class` ?  where are your braces of `Inner{` ending?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the change . Thank you

Comment: @Chris , I edited 'Class' to 'class', just fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. `innerMap` is a *strong* reference to the same object referenced by `outer.outerMap`.  Initializing it via a weak reference to `outer` does not change that.
2. No. The object referenced by `innerMap` will be eligible for GC when there cease to be any live, strong references to it.  That it was once referenced by an instance variable of some class that has since been GC'ed makes no difference.
3. The existence outside `outer` of another reference to the same object referenced by `outer.outerMap` does not inherently prevent the object referenced by `outer` from itself being GC'ed.

As for resources, you could try

- [Understanding weak references](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references), or
- [the API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the references , One follow up question since outerMap still lives on as its referenced by innerMap, would this not mean that the object outer will still continue to live and be prevented from being GC'ed?

Comment: No.  The *object referenced by* `outer.outerMap` (if any) is an independent object.  That the object referenced by `outer` has a **reference** to it does not make one object part of the other, nor does it cause there to be any reference going the other way.  There are ways that you could cause the map to hold a reference to the outer, but none of those are evident in the code you presented.